# DispatchSourceTimer crashes the app with no error on segue

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, grand-central-dispatch

I have a strange behavior that my app crashes after segueing back to a previous view controller. I have a display profile controller and then i go to edit profile controller. I record an audio file there then go back to my previous view controller 1 sec later the app crashes with no error just a

> Thread1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1026eb43c)

I record the audio using `DispatchSourceTimer` to be able to add a counter on the view while recording and i initialized a global variable this way:

```
var nonObservalePropertyUpdateTimes:DispatchSourceTimer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: [], queue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

And here is how i do the recording using a Singltone class called `AudioManager`:

```
@IBAction func micButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if recButtonIsChecked {

        if AudioManager.shared.record(fileName: "recbio") {

        sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pauseProfileButton"), for: .normal)
        playRecordButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "editProfilePlay"), for: .normal)
        recordVoiceLabel.isHidden = true
        recButtonIsChecked = false
        secondsLabel.isHidden = false

        nonObservalePropertyUpdateTimes.resume()

        }


    nonObservalePropertyUpdateTimes.setEventHandler {[weak self] in

        self?.secondsLabel.text = String(describing: AudioManager.shared.countDownTimer)

    }

    nonObservalePropertyUpdateTimes.schedule(deadline: DispatchTime.now(), repeating: DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(100))

    } else {
        sender.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "editProfileMicButton"), for: .normal)
        sender.setImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
        recButtonIsChecked = true
        stopRecording()

    }

}
```

What i believe is that there is something wrong happening in the DispatchQueue that is causing this crash because when i removed the `nonObservalePropertyUpdateTimes` object from my edit profile view controller the app didn't crash when i segue back to my profile view controller.

So i tried to do this but it is not helping:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    nonObservalePropertyUpdateTimes.suspend()
    nonObservalePropertyUpdateTimes.cancel()

}
```

Or maybe there is a way to `deinit` this Dispatch object. I really don't know what is wrong and what to do. I even don't have a proper error message.

Comment: I'd start by suspecting `AudioManager.shared.countDownTimer`. It's unclear what's in that code; but you can explore that being the issue by removing it, and just setting the text to `Date()` or something similar.

Comment: countDownTimer is an Int variable that starts with 15 and then i count down - 1 every 1 second using a timer in the AudioManager class. The recording part is working fine as i said and everything is ok. The problem is in the dispatch because when i do recording without dispatch "of course my label is not being updated" but it doesn't crash when i segue back to my main profile view controller. Because i initialize an instances of the DispatchSourceTimer.

Comment: I'd next swap out the `DispatchSourceTimer` for an `NSTimer`. This will tell if you if the problem is in the `DispatchSource`.

Comment: @RobNapier yes this is what i did. I just didn't initialize a variable of DispatchSourceTimer and it worked. When initializing the variable and just even without doing any recording just when you go to the edit profile view controller and back to the profile view controller it will crash. Maybe it has to do with deinitialising the object. I dont know.

Comment: I haven't built anything with a DispatchSourceTimer in a long time. Many of the other DispatchSources require some care to deallocate (you need to cancel them and wait for their cancelation block to complete before cleaning up resources), but that shouldn't be true for a dispatch timer. The last time I worked on this was in ObjC: https://github.com/rnapier/RNTimer/blob/master/RNTimer/RNTimer.m That example may help you work out what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks every body who tried to help specially Rob. I just deinitialized the DispatchSourceTimer this way and it worked and no more crashing.

```
deinit {
    nonObservalePropertyUpdateTimes.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cancel timer after suspend.You have to resume first then cancel the timer.

https://medium.com/@danielgalasko/a-background-repeating-timer-in-swift-412cecfd2ef9

Comment: kindly consider adding more information from the link as your answer.

Comment: As a result, you must balance each call to dispatch_suspend with a matching call to dispatch_resume before event delivery resumes.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the UI activities run inside main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
self?.secondsLabel.text = String(describing: AudioManager.shared.countDownTimer)

}
```

Comment: Has nothing to do. If you read the DispatchSourceTimer object initialization code that i added in the question you will find that i'm Dispatching on the main queue.